About camel kafka source connector
I want to use the Camel HTTP Source Connector as the HTTP Source Connector among the Kafka Connectors.
As a result of REST Endpoint, json is as follows.
{
    "list": [
        {
            "id": 10,
            "contents": "Test"
        }
    ]
}

To add this value to the Kafka cluster topic, I added the source connector as follows.
{
    "name": "camel-http-source",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.httpsource.CamelHttpsourceSourceConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "camel.source.endpoint.httpMethod": "GET",
        "camel.source.endpoint.dataFormat": "json",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "topics": "http-topic-2",
        "camel.kamelet.http-source.url": "http://localhost:8080/bom/api/v1/sample/list",
        "camel.kamelet.http-source.contentType": "application/json"
    }
}

At this time, the following error occurs.
trace:org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:230)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.convertTransformedRecord(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:488)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:396)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.execute(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:361)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:204)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:259)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.run(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:75)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.lambda$withClassLoader$1(Plugins.java:181)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Invalid type for bytes type: class org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.convertToJson(JsonConverter.java:653)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.convertToJsonWithEnvelope(JsonConverter.java:592)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.fromConnectData(JsonConverter.java:346)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.fromConnectData(Converter.java:64)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.lambda$convertTransformedRecord$6(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:488)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:214)
    ... 13 more

my kafka version : 3.5.1
camel connector version : 4.0.x(LTS)
How can I correct this error?
